# extension theorem for valuations

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

I am reading over the theorem of extensions of valuation as you can find it for example in Neukirch's book about number theory:

$ $Let $(K,v)$ be a (archimedian or non-archimedian) valued field, $f \in K[X]$ an irreducible polynomial and $L=K(\alpha)$ a simple field extension, where $f(\alpha)=0$. Assume that over $K_v[X]$, where $K_v$ denotes the completion of $K$ w.r.t. $v$, $f$ decomposes into
$$f(X)=\prod_{i=1}^r f_i(X)^{m_i}$$
with $r$ distinct irreducible factors $f_i \in K_v[X]$. Then these factors $f_1, \ldots, f_r$ uniquely correspond to the extensions $w_1,\ldots, w_r$ of $v$ on $L$.

Before that we have already seen the following:

$ $Any extension $w$ of the valuation $v$ on $L$ is of the form $w=\overline{v} \circ \tau$, where $\overline{K}_v$ denotes the algebraic closure of $K_v$, $\tau: L \hookrightarrow \overline{K}_v$ is a $K$-embedding of $L$ and $\overline{v}$ denotes the unique extension of $v$ on $\overline{K}_v$. If $w_1=\overline{v} \circ \tau_1$, $w_2=\overline{v}\circ \tau_2$ are two extension, then they agree if and only if $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are conjugate, i.e. if there is some $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}_v/K_v)$ with $\sigma(\tau_1) =\tau_2$.

Now my original problem occurred when trying to compute an explicit example.

$ $Let $K=\mathbb{Q}$ equipped with the usual archimedean valuation $v=\lvert \cdot \rvert_{\infty}$ and let $f=X^3-5$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$. Over $K_v=\mathbb{R}$ we have a decomposition of $f$ into $$f(X)=(X-\sqrt[3]{5})(X^2+\sqrt[3]{5}X+\sqrt[3]{25})$$
with two irreducible factors $f_1, f_2$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, following the theorem above, we should have two extensions of $v$ on $L$. Moreover we know that these extensions must be of the form $w=\overline{v}\circ \tau$, where $\overline{v}$ is the extension of $v$ on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{C}$ and $\tau$ are the $\mathbb{Q}$-embeddings of $L$. These are given by
$$\tau_i: L \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}, \qquad \sqrt[3]{5} \mapsto  \begin{cases} \ \sqrt[3]{5}, & \textrm{ für }i=1, \\ \ \zeta \sqrt[3]{5}, & \textrm{ für }i=2, \\ \ \zeta^2 \sqrt[3]{5} & \textrm{ für }i=3. \end{cases}$$
with some primitive third root of unity $\zeta$. Further $\overline{v}$ is the usual complex valuation.

Now the problem is:

$ $ $$w_i=\overline{v} \circ \tau_i$$
for $i=1,2,3$ agree, since on $\mathbb{Q}$ they are the identity and we have
$$w_i(\sqrt[3]{5}) = (\overline{v} \circ \tau_i)(\sqrt[3]{5}) = \overline{v}(\zeta^{i-1} \sqrt[3]{5}) = \sqrt[3]{5}.$$

So all in all for me there seems to be only one extension of $v$ and honestly I cannot think of a second one extending $v$. Where is my mistake?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Write $\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}\al=\sqrt[3]5$. A typical element of $L$ is $a+b\al+c\al^2$ where $a$, $b$, $c\in\Bbb Q$. The two Archimedean valuations (up to equivalence) on $L$ are
$$v_1(a+b\al+c\al^2)=|a+b\sqrt[3]5+c\sqrt[3]{25}|$$
and
$$\newcommand{\om}{\zeta}
v_2(a+b\al+c\al^2)=|a+\om b\sqrt[3]5+\om^2 c\sqrt[3]{25}|
=\sqrt{(a-b\sqrt[3]5/2-c\sqrt[3]{25}/2)^2+3(b\sqrt[3]5-c\sqrt[3]{25})^2/4}.$$
($\om=\exp(2\pi i/3)$.)
These are as inequivalent as they look.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So indeed my problem was assuming that these two valuations are equivalent since they agree for $1, \alpha, \alpha^2$. To see, that they are inequivalent, I would proceed as follows: Two valuations are equivalent if one is a power of another. Since they agree for $\alpha$, this power should be $1$. This contradicts to the fact that they are not equal, as for example the element $1+\alpha + \alpha^2$ is valued differently under these two. Is that good?

Comment: @Arthur That's right. Also with some patience, you can find some $\beta$ with $v_1(\beta)<1$ and $v_2(\beta)>1$ so that $\beta^n$ converges to zero with respect to $v_1$ and diverges with respect to $v_2$.

Comment: That's true. With less patience than expected I found that $\beta=-1+\alpha$ satisfies $v_1(\beta)=0.71$ and $v_2(\beta) = 3.09$. I thank you so much for your help!